# Will updating the page title without changing the URL hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, url, title

I have a website and I want to update some titles of its pages, e.g.

"White wine" i want to change to "French White Wine", but I do not want to change URL, i.e. I would prefer to leave it as it was `https://example.com/white_wine`.

Can you tell me is it OK to do so or it will affect SEO in a bad way?

Answer (score 3):

Totally fine to do this. In fact, it could even be advantageous for reasons to do with semantics.

However, I'd recommend changing the slug from `/white_wine` to `/white-wine`.

This is because if you use an underscore Google will combine the two words on either side of the `_` into one word.

`/white_wine` === "whitewine"

`/white-wine` === "white wine"

In order for your page to rank the best it can for searches that include "white wine", you'd want a dash instead.

So when you go to change the title and slug don't forget to apply a 301 redirect.

Comment: Thank you, very much!

Comment: You're very welcome. If my answer solved your problem, kindly select the "accept" option beneath the vote counter.